# как написать приложение на андроид для wordpress сайта

Tags: android, wordpress

Здравствуйте, мне нужна помощь в написании приложения на андроид которое будет выводить новости с сайта вордпресс, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Недавно пилил приложение к API написанному на php для wordpress. Если возьмётесь писать API - готовьтесь к дикой боли - с wordpress работать аццки сложно.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно реализовать Api на сайте которое, по обращению будет возвращать данные, сейчас уже все юзают REST(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE запросы).

Для написания такого Api можно использовать PHP.

В Android если выберешь REST, то можешь выбрать библиотеку Retrofit(одна из лучших, и многофункциональная библиотека).

P/s примеров очень много по Api, так из Retrofit.